# How to broadcast to multiple iOS devices via BLE from a non-iOS device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently trying to broadcast a message to multiple iOS/Android devices from an Arduino Mega (with HM10 module) or alternatively from a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

**What I've learned so far:**

- BLE only supports one connection at a time
- iOS does not support classic Bluetooth unless MFI certified (not an option)
- iOS does not support Wi-Fi direct (would solve the multi-connect problem)
- Using BLE advertisements would be an option but HM10 apparently does not support advertisements over 1 byte long (need approx. 20)
- Also looked into creating a WPAN from the Pi (host) because apparently there is a way (which I have not yet found) to get this to work with iOS devices
- There is a straightforward library for ESP32 ([GitHub Repo](https://github.com/lucascoelhof/ESP32BleAdvertise)), does anyone have experience with that?

So, in short: BLE only connects to one device, except for advertisements which are limited on HM10 and insanely complicated on the Raspberry Pi; Wi-Fi direct is not supported by iOS

**The question:** Has anyone solved this problem so far? If no, are there any suggestions on what could help?

**Edit:** @Emil's comment got me thinking about turning the Arduino/Pi into the client and thr phonrs into slaves. This would mean that multiple phones could connect. The only problem: how do phones 'actively' connect when they are in the peripheral role?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Who said "BLE only connects to one device"? It's not really true...

Comment: You're right.. I forgot to say that the Pi/Arduino would be in a peripheral role and peripherals only support one connection at a time.

Comment: The requirement of the limitation of one slave connection was removed in Bluetooth 4.1. The Pi Zero W has a BCM43438 chip which supports multiple slave connections!

Comment: Oh! Awesome! I completely missed that - tank you.